# Learning different strategies?

Tags: strategy

Ok, So I learned how to play chess yrs ago, but suck at it-and wanna knw if there are any nice strategies to beat your opponents? If so can you guys tell me about it and explained the whole concept to pretty please?

Comment: Can't answer without knowing how bad a player you are.  Do you have a USCF rating?

Comment: Consider picking up an introduction to tactics. Books are usually best here, and everyone has a favorite. I particularly like Winning Chess Tactics by Bill Robertie.

Comment: This question is too broad, it basically comes down to "how do you play chess well".

Comment: There are various strategies to achieve what you want. You can defeat your opponent in an endgame/play for a mating attack/positionally overpower him/tactically outwit him and so on... To describe all of these would not fit into a single post. You need to learn all those and to do that it is best to start with one by one approach. Pick a topic that is **less broad**, post a question about it here, and we will help you. I would recommend you to start with openings. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

There are three phases of the chess game - **opening**, **middlegame** and **endgame**. You should learn about these. Also, as a human being there is also the **psychological** aspect of the game. Then there are also **free chess programs** that you can use to analyze your games. So you may want to look into various threads on this site that are related to these topics.

Look for tags like [opening](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening), [middlegame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middlegame), [endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endgame), [software](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software), [training](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training), [tactics](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics), [strategy](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy), etc.

There are plenty of threads on these topics, so I'll be a bit biased and recommend some of my own answers :D -

**Psychological**

[How to start learning chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/where-i-can-start-to-learn/5213#5213)

[What advice wold you give to a novice in chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/what-advice-would-you-give-a-novice-in-chess/4782#4782)

[What to do after losing a game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4763/what-to-do-after-losing-a-game/4768#4768)

**Opening**

[Why is the center of the board considered important in chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5142/why-is-the-centre-of-the-board-considered-important-in-chess/5143#5143)

[Should I understand openings or just memorize them?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/understanding-vs-memorization/5286#5286)

[What opening traps can I set that do not weaken my position?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5429/chess-traps-without-positional-loss/5431#5431)

**Middlegame**

[What are some good middlegame plans and strategies?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/what-are-some-good-middle-game-plans-or-strategies/5052#5052)

[What is prophylaxis and why is it important?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/overprotection-and-prophylaxis/4828#4828)

**Endgame**

[How do I improve my endgame?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/941/improving-the-endgame-principles)

[How do I checkmate with a queen](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/how-do-you-checkmate-with-a-queen/4935#4935)[, with a rook](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/how-do-you-checkmate-with-a-rook/4890#4890)[, and with bishops?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4931/how-do-you-checkmate-with-the-pair-of-bishops/4943#4943)

**Software**

[Websites for practicing chess tactics](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/what-are-the-options-for-solving-puzzles-online-and-tracking-progress/5381#5381)

[Free Chess Software](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27/is-there-any-free-software-to-automatically-analyze-and-annotate-games)